# How do I leave a recursive loop and not print anything if a solution cannot be found?

Tags: c++

I have a game and the point of the game is to find a solution within 21 turns. If it can't find a solution, it should output "No solution" and continue on in the main. If there is a solution, it is supposed to go up the stack and output every step (backwards is fine for now).

I am trying to figure out how to leave my stack without printing anything when I can't find a solution. At the moment it will print "No solution in 21 turns." but then still go up the stack, printing every move. When there is a solution, it does work.

```
bool TabletStock(int _tablets, int _turns) {
   if (_tablets == 18){
       cout << "Found solution. I have exactly 18 tablets, with " << 21 - _turns << " moves left.\n";
       return 1;
   }

   _turns++;

   if (_turns >= 21){
       cout << "No solution in 21 turns.\n";
       return 0;
   }

   if (_tablets % 2 == 1){
       TabletStock((++_tablets) / 2, _turns);
       cout << "After incrementing, reduce " << _tablets << " by half to get " << _tablets / 2 << ".\n";
   }
   else if (_tablets % 3 == 0 && _tablets % 18 == 0){
      TabletStock(_tablets / 3, _turns);
      cout << "With " << _tablets << ", divide by 3 to get " << _tablets / 3 << ".\n";
   }
   else{
      TabletStock((_tablets + 24), _turns);
      cout << "With " << _tablets << ", add 24 to get " << _tablets + 24 << ".\n";
   }
}
```

The function call at the moment is TabletStock(int, 0);

I have been trying to do something in the "if (_turns >= 21)" statement since that prints before it prints all the steps, so if I found a way to "break" from the stack in that if statement, maybe I could get it to not output all the cout steps.

Comment: You can throw exception to leave the stack

Comment: Your compiler should warn you that you're missing a return value.

Answer (score 1):

When you call your TabletStock() it will return bool. Every print should be wrapped with an if statement. If it's false don't print.

For example, change this:

```
TabletStock((_tablets + 24), _turns);
cout << "With " << _tablets << ", add 24 to get " << _tablets + 24 << ".\n";
```

To:

```
if(TabletStock((_tablets + 24), _turns))
{
    cout << "With " << _tablets << ", add 24 to get " << _tablets + 24 << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: I like this, so the function will still happen, but will only output if that returns true?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your string in a variable outside of scope or add it in your function paramater, each time you append your result in the string variable.

```
if (_tablets % 3 == 0 && _tablets % 18 == 0) 
{
    mystring += "After incrementing, reduce ....... ";
    TabletStock(_tablets / 3, _turns);
}
```

and if at the end:

```
if (_tablets == 18) 
{
    cout << mystring << endl;
    return 1;
}
```